# Go to the Running Safari And Press Enter Using AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I'm very new to AppleScript and I'm trying to do this. I have an Safari process running on my machine. I wish I could go to the running safari and stimulate an enter key event.

Is it possible to do so?

The code I'm trying is:

```
on is_running(appName)
    tell application "System Events" to (name of processes) contains appName
end is_running

set safRunning to is_running("Safari")
if safRunning then
    run script "tell application \"Safari\" 
         key code 36
    end tell"
    return "Running"
else
    return "Not running"
end if
```

Inside the `run script` the `key code 36` (for stimulating enter) is giving me error:

```
error "Expected end of line but found identifier." number -2741
```

Any guesses where I'm making mistake?

Answer (score 9):

The "System Events" must to the key pressing.

for example:

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    tell application "System Events" to key code 36 #return
end tell
```

I don't know, what the key pressing is for, so now has no effect.

A working example, where the download list is shown and then by pressing "space" the list is cleared:

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "l" using {command down, option down} # cmd-opt-l
    delay 1
    tell application "System Events" to key code 49 #space
end tell
```